# Glassfish 4.1 TransactionalException cause bug

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, glassfish

I'm using Glassfish 4.1 with JPA, JSF and CDI. My service layer who does the persistence is annotated with @Transactional. The problem or the bug is: If any exception is thrown, it is wrapped in a TransactionException, but you cannot get the original exception of it. In the TransactionalException in the "cause" attribut is the same Transactional exception again. Why does it happen? I couldn't find any workaround in the internet yet.

Here is a picture of the debug log from intellij idea:

[image: Debug of Intellij]